# In a Blazor component library, is there a way to change the 'base' for its components?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In a server-side Blazor app (for example, use the Visual Studio template project), I can add a Razor component "Hello.razor", containing:

`<h3>Hello</h3><img src="images/hello.jpg" />`

and inside the project's `wwwroot` folder, I can put an `images` folder, and put the `hello.jpg` inside that. That all works.

Now I want to move that component into a Razor Component Library called "RazorComponentLibraryOne", so I move the "Hello.razor" into the component library project, and move the "hello.jpg" file into that project's "wwwroot\images" folder.

To make this work, I need to change the `img src` location location to be:

`<img src="_content/RazorComponentLibraryOne/images/hello.jpg" />`

It feels like there should be a cleverer way of doing this, but I haven't found it. The "Don't repeat yourself" principle is telling me that it isn't clever to have to be inserting the `_content/RazorComponentLibraryOne` prefix all over the place, so I'd like to do it in one place in the library. If it could be done, this would also solve the  blue-squiggle underline that Visual Studio gives the `src` value, since it doesn't understand that prefix.

I was wondering whether there is something I could do within the component library, a bit like the `<base href="~/" />` which is done in the server-side project's `_Layout.cshtml`, so that I can put that relative path in a single place within the component library, allowing things like the `img src` to remain unchanged between being in the main project or being in a component library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything built in, but you can build your own.

A library constant for the base url.

```
public static class LibrarySettings
{
    public const string ImageUrl = "./";
}
```

`MyImg` component:

```
<img src="@_url" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? Src { get; set; }

    private string _url => $"{LibrarySettings.ImageUrl}{Src}";
}
```

And in use:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="m-2">
    <MyImg src="favicon.png" />
</div>
<div class="m-2">
    <img src="./favicon.png" />
</div>
```